# MediaElement.js Internet Explorer 8 showing blocky rectangles

Tags: internet-explorer-8, mediaelement.js

I am using the **MediaElement.js** Wordpress plugin in order to play MP3s on my homepage.

But on Internet Explorer 8 I have trouble with the plugin.

Instead of the play button and the volume button, it only shows a *blocky rectangle*. 
I have tested on two different computers with the same result.

You can test it here: http://www.alatarmusic.com/noise-reduction/

It works fine with Firefox and with Safari on my iPhone. And I know, that other sites show up fine in my Internet Explorer. For example, the player on [MediaElementJS.com](http://mediaelementjs.com/) looks correct. It seems, something is wrong with my homepage?

But what could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Was having the same issue in IE7 as well as IE8:

[image]

The fix for me was making sure the filter style was reset:

```
filter: none;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your [style-sheet](http://www.alatarmusic.com/wp-content/themes/website/data/php/attach.php?f=fancybox.css,flexslider.css,tipsy.css,base.css,structure.css,parts.css,widgets.css,plugins.css,bright.css) contains the following CSS:

```
.post .content button{background:linear-gradient(top,#ffffff 0%,#e9e9e9 100%);-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff',endColorstr='#e9e9e9')";
```

Beautified:

```
.post .content button {
    background: linear-gradient(top,#ffffff 0%,#e9e9e9 100%);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff',endColorstr='#e9e9e9')";
}
```

The last property, [`-ms-filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), is a proprietary CSS extension by Microsoft, which is only parsed by Internet Explorer.

The color `#ffffff` is white, and the color [`#e9e9e9`](http://jsbin.com/ewevam/) is light gray.

Because the effect does only work in Internet Explorer, only IE users will see a light-colored rectangle instead of a play button.

Setting the `filter` to `none` gives back the button:
[image: Screenshot: The "filter" for the buttons is set to "none".]

This markup does probably effect other buttons in your Wordpress blog, so removing it might not be an option. Instead, you can add `filter:none` to the CSS for `.mejs-button`; e.g.:

```
.mejs-button{
    filter: none;
}
```